# Global Client Validation in ASP.NET Web Forms using CustomValidation.ClientValidationFunction

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have two `TextBox` fields in a web form that are validated as dates using the `CustomValidation` element. An excerpt of how I set this up is as follows (includes the fields and the Javascript validator):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateParam1(sender, args)
    {
        var dt = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt01');


        args.IsValid = dt.value.length > 0 ? (/([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/.](19|20)\d\d/.test(dt.value) ? true : false) : true;
    }

    function dateParam2(sender, args)
    {
        var  dt = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt02');


        args.IsValid = dt.value.length > 0 ? (/([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/.](19|20)\d\d/.test(dt.value) ? true : false) : true;
    }
</script>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl01" runat="server" Width="600px" Visible="False">
    <table>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td width="250px" align="right">
                 <asp:Label ID="lbl01" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt01" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvP01" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidateEmptyText="True" ControlToValidate="txt01" ClientValidationFunction="dateParam1" ></asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl01a" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#000066" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl02" runat="server" Width="600px" Visible="False">
    <table>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td width="250px" align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl02" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt02" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl02a" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#000066" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvP02" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidateEmptyText="True" ControlToValidate="txt02" ClientValidationFunction="dateParam2" ></asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

As you can see, I have two separate validation elements and functions for each textbox. However, although both validations correspond to separate Text Boxes, the validation being done to both of them are exactly the same (i.e. evaluating how the dates should look and what they contain)

My question is: is there a way to make a single validation function that could validate all specified text boxes as dates, not only on this page, but across the entire application?

I have attempted to implement a global Javascript function by adding it to the Master file. This works but it requires the specific ID of the element you are trying to validate. It is possible to give every date text box throughout the application the same ID, but this would not work if you have two date fields on the same page. Is it possible to get the value passed to the function through  either `sender` or `args`?

If it makes any difference, my code-behind is written in C#.

**Edit:** I'm looking to see if this is possible by specifically by using the CustomValidation.ClientValidationFunction property

Comment: Are you using jquery or any other document traversal library?

Comment: @WillP. No, the application uses strictly JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try below;

```
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl01" runat="server" Width="600px" Visible="true">
        <table>
            <tr valign="middle">
                <td width="250px" align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl01" runat="server" Text="Text1"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt01" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="test"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl01a" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#000066"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl02" runat="server" Width="600px" Visible="True">
        <table>
            <tr valign="middle">
                <td width="250px" align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl02" runat="server" Text="Text2"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt02" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="test"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl02a" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#000066"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

`

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".test").focusout(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var str = elem.val();
        var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
        if (date_regex.test(str))
        {
            alert('Great, you entered correct date value');
            $(this).removeClass('focus');
            elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        }
        else {
            
            alert('invalid value');
            $(this).addClass('focus');
       
        }
    });

    </script>
```

```css
    <style type="text/css">
        .focus
        {
            border:solid 2px;
            border-color:red;
        }
    </style>
```

I have made

- ASP.Net panel visible=true just for checking purposes.
- Added CssClass property="test" for textboxes which need to be validated
- Then in the JavaScript it checks for the "focusout" event of the selected element with the CssClass="test. It will get the text input and validates against the given date regex.
- In the styles I have added a class named focus and this class will be added to the selected textbox with the CssClass="test" and it will highlight the textbox in red colour which has the invalid data.
- When the selected element has correct data, newly added styles will be removed.

Customize the outputs in the JavaScript and Stylesheet.